# Existence of unique solution in Banach space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $L : X → X$ be a bounded linear operator. Are there situations where $||L||>1$ for which there is a unique solution to $x=Lx+b$? Explain your answer.

**My attempt:** The answer is there isn't a unique one, since $||L||>1$ implies that there doesn't exit an inverse operator $(I-L)^{-1}$ (by a well-known theorem that I forgot the name)... so the equation $(I-L)x = b$ cannot have unique solution for every $b$. Is this the correct reasoning? If not, can somebody help with the correct one?

Comment: There are certainly situations where this occurs. In finite dimensions it occurs whenever 1 is not an eigenvalue of $L $. Even in infinite dimensions it could occur, for instance  with $L=cI $ for $c \neq  1$

Comment: @Ian: thank you for your answer. But can you please elaborate on each of the cases above, so that I can see why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $L(x) = 2 x$ for $x \in \Bbb{R}$

$$x = 2 x + b \Rightarrow x = -b \text{ is the unique solution}$$

Comment: Great example, Conrado!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me elaborate on the comment of Ian. Indeed you can characterize the solvability by the spectrum of the operator.

As you wrote, the equation is has a unique solution for every $b$, iff $I-L$ is invertible. This is equivalent to $0 \not\in \sigma(I-L)$ and to $1 \not\in \sigma(L)$. And there are many examples for such $L$.